# Iterate through a PyMongo collection

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing, iteration, pymongo

I need to iterate through my collection and get all the values from the keys with the same name.

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "59b3824b44e96c07dceba8de"
        },
        "place": "Yellow Stone",
        "time": "2017-09-08",
        "user": "user@gmail.com",
        "user_go": "yes"
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "59b4ea8644e96c37c43be33a"
        },
        "place": "Yosemite",
        "time": "2017-11-10",
        "user": "user@gmail.com",
        "user_go": "yes"
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "59b4ea9144e96c37c43be344"
        },
        "place": "Devils Tower",
        "time": "2017-09-10",
        "user": "user@gmail.com",
        "user_go": "yes"
    },
]
```

I'm wondering how I would get all the place names from from the collection based on the username. I've tried doing something similar to this:

```
data = db.voting.find({'user' : 'user@gmail.com'})
data = dumps(data)

parsed = json.loads(data)

for x in parsed:
     for key,value in x.items():
         print("values: {}".format(value))
```

As you might guess I get all the values for all the keys, how to get just the values for keys I want? I've also tried `place = parsed[0]['place']` but that only returns the first "place" value not all values. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but this is proving tricky to wrap my head around.

I also was reading through the docs and found [cursour.forEach](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) but can't find a good example of how to use it.

Comment: Or you just use [`distinct()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct). i.e `db.voting.distinct('place', {'user' : 'user@gmail.com'})`. Which returns a list of the "distinct" places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x['place']` is what you're looking for.

```
for x in parsed:
     place = x['place']
     ... # do something with place
```

Comment: Perfect, I'll accept when the time is up. I feel like an idiot, that was too easy. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BrettJ Happens to every beginner :)